# Automatic solution to reduce Linux kernel package size at compile time

Tags: linux, kernel, configure

Are there automatic solutions to disable unused Linux kernel parts (in particular unused modules) before compilation to fasten compilation?

A daemon, that logs used kernel functions (or modules) at runtime and disables unused functions afterwards in the `.config`, so more dynamic information gathering than `make localmodconfig` would be cool.

Another problem with `localmodconfig` are removable devices. Modules which are only loaded from time to time are not taken into account by this solution.

Comment: Why do you ask? What is the use case? On most distributions, there is `initrd` and a lot of kernel modules, and you can set up your system to load a minimal amount of kernel modules.

Comment: Compiling would be much faster.

Comment: Then you just have to configure your own kernel to remove the modules you don't use (so answer `N` instead of `M`)

Comment: Yes, I know. That's the question for. Is there an automatic (!) solution for this task?

Comment: No you are asking about kernel *functions* I was talking about kernel *modules*, this is not the same. So at least edit the title & the question. And not compiling a module won't change much the kernel (non-modules) size, it will just make the build not compile that module, hence reduce the build *time*, not the kernel's *size*.

Comment: OK, I was not specific, but it was clear what I meant. `.configure` implicates it is about compiling. And you would have to log "functions", to see which modules were actually used and not just loaded, right?

Comment: A module may provide several functions, and some functions (e.g. most syscalls) are not provided by modules

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning and what follows of that. Doesn't matter that most syscalls are not in modules. The only target is a minimal `.config`.

Comment: Compiling a custom kernel usinig a mimimalist configuration depends on the distribution type, as each distribution has and uses different tools to package the end result.  Your post doesn't mention your OS.  You can't understand what Basile is getting at until you've seen at least a `menuconfig` of a kernel, and I'd be happy to help but I need the OS version to do so.

Comment: My reasoning is that the word "function" or even "feature" is wrong. You mean "kernel module"; these are the only things you could realistically skip. Anything else requires major kernel surgery, which you won't be able doing unless you are a significant kernel contributor (and then, you'll understand that it is hopeless)